# Open GL draw static Points

Tags: opengl, static, drawing, cloud, point

Is it posible to draw a static Point-Cloud in Open-GL

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

for(float x = -1; x < 1; x += 0.1) 
{
    for(float y = -1; y < 1; y += 0.1) 
    {
        for(float z = -1; z < 1; z += 0.1)
        {
            float d = 1-sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
            glColor3f(d, d, d);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}

glEnd();
```

and later to e.g. rotate around this Cloud ? Without drawing it everytime again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm getting tired of this, but here it goes again:

**OpenGL is not a scene graph!** OpenGL does not maintain a scene. It's a drawing API, that provides you with drawing tools to draw onto a canvas. It draws points, lines and triangles, and once a primitive has been drawn, OpenGL has no recollection of it. The only remains are pixels with a changed color in a framebuffer.

Old OpenGL (before and including OpenGL-2.1) had a facility called "display lists" which allows to record kind of "macros" of drawing commands. They sort of behave a bit like a "scene", but they are not. They're just a list of drawing commands.

So if you change something, and be it only the point of view, you have to redraw the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a soulution:

Precompute the Points save them in a Array and render the whole Array.

Comment: So what you meant with "without draw it everytime again" was to find a way to not *compute* the points every frame?